# Unable to see the effect of text-overflow

Tags: html, css

```css
.textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.clip {
  text-overflow: clip;
}

.ellipsis {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea clip">
  <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five </p>
</div>
<div class="textarea ellipsis">
  <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
</div>
```

Here after setting the value `text-overflow:ellipsis` ,I am not getting three dot(...) which should come ,if there is more text given that width is not so much enough to accommodate all the text.

I have tried with different width values but no required result is coming.

Answer (score 1):

Because `overflow` and `text-overflow` in not an inherited property and you have applied it on `.textarea` so no effect on the `<p>` will take place.

You can apply `white-space:nowrap` to the `.textarea` as it is an inherited css property.

So apply `overflow:hidden` and `text-overflow` to the `<p>` instead of `.textarea`..

Also you have a typo error in your above code...`textarea` will be `.textarea` because its a class not a tag

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.clip p {
  text-overflow: clip;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ellipsis p {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea clip">
  <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five </p>
</div>
<div class="textarea ellipsis">
  <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
</div>
```

Comment: It is really a awesome explanation @tx Bhuwan

Comment: Hi Bhuvan Can u suggest me some online reference or books where I can have a brief understanding about html css

Comment: @Danny if you are newbie in HTML,CSS you can follow w3school for now and try to implement all the `properties` and `tags` practically...For more deep info you can use **[HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML)** and **[CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)**

Comment: @Danny if this solution resolved your issue, you can accept the answer to tell the community that this question is solved...[**How accepting works**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)